# Create batch of sites Wordpress MultiSite

Tags: multisite

WP MulsiSite is very useful to me. Now I would like to add +100 sites to my existing installation. I've seen many scripts/plugins for adding new users to WPMU.

What script should I use in order to add a batch of new sites (including new users)?

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the command line of this install as it is hosted by a hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got command-line access, [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) could be the solution you need.

You could write up a quick shell script:

```
wp site create --slug=site1
wp user create joe joe@example.com --role=administrator --url=example.com/site1
```

... and so forth.

### References

- [Installing wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/#installing)
- [`wp site` commands](http://wp-cli.org/commands/site/)
- [`wp user` commands](http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/)

Comment: In addition to @PatJ's answer, be aware that each new site creates 8-9 (about) new tables in your database. So you have to be careful that your hosting place will be OK with that...the 'basic' (shared) hosting places might require you to upgrade to a non-shared server, or they will suspend your account.